# How the answer of this question is 4?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm learning Sets and at current about Power Set. I'm confused in a example given in my book. Please have a look at the image. [image: Image 1]

I didn't get the last two lines of the solution. Please help. Thankyou in advance.

Comment: In the third line, you are finding the power set of the set in the second line.  The last line just states that the set in the third line has four elements.

Answer (score 4):

Probably the clustering of empty set symbols and nested set braces is the most confusing here.

- The empty set has only one subset: $\emptyset$ itself, hence $P(\emptyset)$ is a one-element set with $\emptyset$ as only element.
- For *any* one-element set $X=\{a\}$ we have $P(X)=\{\emptyset,X\}$ as the empty set and the full set itself are the only subsets of $X$. Hence $P(P(\emptyset))$ is a two-element set.
- For *any* two-element set $X=\{a,b\}$ (note that $a\ne b$), there are precisely four subsets of $X$, namely $\emptyset$ and $\{a\}$ and $\{b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$. Hence $P(P(P(\emptyset)))$ is a four-element set.
  If you recall that $a=\emptyset$ and $b=\{\emptyset\}$ we can expand the enumaration of $P(P(P(\emptyset)))$:
  $$ P(P(P(\emptyset)))=\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}=\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\}$$

---

If you want so experience an even more confusing notation, use $\{\}$ for $\emptyset$: 
$$ P(P(P(\{\})))=\{\{\},\{\{\}\},\{\{\{\}\}\},\{\{\},\{\{\}\}\}\}$$

Comment: Thankyou.It helped me alot.

Comment: I didn't get the second point. how $P(P(phi))$ is a two element set?

Answer (score 2):

We can solve this problem rather easily by recalling that if $A$ is a set with cardinality $k$, then the set $P(A)$ has cardinality $2^k$.

First, the cardinality of $\phi$ is $0$. Applying the above principle, the cardinality of $P(\phi)$ is $2^0=1$. Then the cardinality of $P(P(\phi))$ is $2^1=2$. Finally, the cardinality of $P[P(P(\phi))]$ is $2^2=4$.

Answer (score 0):

Subsets of $P(P(\phi))=\{\phi,\{\phi\}\}$ are $\{\phi\}$,$\{\{\phi\}\}$,$P(P(\phi))$ itself and empty set i.e. $\phi$ again.

(Remember that empty set and the whole set are always subsets of a given set.)

Hence $P(P(P(\phi)))=\{\phi,\{\phi\},\{\{\phi\}\},P(P(\phi))=\{\phi,\{\phi\}\}\}$.

Comment: how $P(P(phi))$ is a two element set?

Comment: $P(P(\phi))$ is power set of $P(\phi)=\{\phi\}$ and subsets of $P(\phi)$ are $P(\phi)$ itself and empty set which is $\phi$. Hence $P(P(\phi))=\{\phi,P(\phi)=\{\phi\}\}$. Hence $P(P(\phi))$ has two elements.

Answer (score -3):

think $a=\phi ,b=\{\phi \}$, then $P[\{a,b\}]=\{\phi,\{a\},\{b\},\{a,b\}\}$